# How much time does EU to Switzerland transfer take?

Tags: international-transfer, european-union, switzerland

How much time does it take a regular money transfer to complete, started from an EUR account from the EU to a CHF account in Switzerland? The transaction was started as a normal transaction (nothing express), in CHF. Looked on the internet everywhere, but couldn't find any info on this, except some laws about SEPA, that does not seem to be relevant here.

If it matters, the source account is in Slovakia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes about 4-5 workdays, maybe it depends on the day also when you start the transfer.
I transferred an amount last Wednesday, and the same amount on Thursday too. Both transactions hit the destination account on the next Tuesday, with a difference of 2 minutes.